Why does "cat | wc -c" shows different size than "ls -l" for a specific file?
The distro is Ubuntu 22.04 and I'm running a newly-created ext4 filesystem that I have copied my setup to (using rsync on a different machine). I was running a manually written (python) filesystem performance test, which worked normally on different machines. Absolutely acidentally I discovered some sort of incorrect behavior in wc (or ls) which manifests itself only for a particular file on my system - as far as I have discovered now - /usr/bin/pkexec. If this is related, the box is running official Ubuntu's coreutils version 8.32-4.
This is an example of the action I'm talking about for any different file:
$ ls -l /usr/bin/top
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 379389 Jun 11 12:04 /usr/bin/top
$ cat /usr/bin/top | wc -c
379389
$

Note the size shown by ls and wc. It is the same.
Now, there is a file /usr/bin/pkexec. Which is, according to man page,
      pkexec - Execute a command as another user

This happens with it
$ ls -l /usr/bin/pkexec
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 519851 Jun  11 12:04 /usr/bin/pkexec
$ cat /usr/bin/pkexec | wc -c
32145
$

The size is different. Quite really different.

I thought that it is related to some filesystem corruption, and I ran fsck in recovery mode. Nothing have changed.

Then I took the disk to the machine where the rsync was originally done. (It is running Arch Linux). I mounted the Ubuntu's root partition there. Wow!
# ls -l /mnt/disk/usr/bin/pkexec
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 519851 Jun  11 12:04 /mnt/disk/usr/bin/pkexec
# cat /mnt/disk/usr/bin/pkexec | wc -c
519851
#

Here the sizes are shown equal. I do not understand. I have a different Ubuntu box with the same version where the information about the above file is this:
$ ls -l /usr/bin/pkexec
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 32145 Jul  26 14:45 /usr/bin/pkexec
$ cat /usr/bin/pkexec | wc -c
32145
$

The size matches here. And I see that the correct size for this file in this version of Ubuntu is "32145". But on the first machine I see sizes which don't even match each other in wc and ls. I had these explanations possibly

Machines had different updates installed.
But why are the sizes shown different between utilities?
This is some sort of runtime protection for this /usr/bin/pkexec binary file, as I see that it's SUID - maybe OS is protecting it by showing incorrect data to users?
But why this behavior is seen only on one machine then and not the others?

Thanks for help and explanations. I think I don't understand something important about Linux.
P.S. The problem also exists if I read dir "/usr/bin" in some langs like Python, and retrieve metadata of files. Then I read each file and check the result length. With pkexec - in metadata it's 519851 bytes. But if I read the file , it's much shorter - only 32145 bytes. Thanks.

I'm not sure if relevant, but when booting this particular machine I see many messages on console which I don't understand: one was bash uses obsolete (PF_INIT, SOCK_PACKET)and all other similar but different programs in place of"bash"

I believe ls is giving you the size the file system has allocated for the file (sometimes referred to as "size on disk"), while wc is giving you the count of actual bytes in the file.  Saying that, of course, doesn't explain why the file system has allocated all of this additional space.

See for example https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363572/why-is-the-difference-in-file-size-and-its-size-on-disk-bigger-than-4-kib

@Malcolm - ls -l definitely does not give "size on disk"

by the way pkexec is nowhere near 519KB on any system I own - biggest I've seen is about 67KB on arm64, and 26KB on amd64

@JaromandaX what makes you so sure of that.  The man page for ls is not extremely clear on the subject, but the documentation for the -s flag does explicitly say that the size it prints is the "allocated size of each file"  If it were calculating the size differently in different cases, I would have thought the man page would have been more explicit about the difference.

ls -s shows the size (in blocks) of the file as a separate value - this has absolutely nothing to do with the -l flag - I've been using linux since the initial release in 1991, and before that worked with a multitude of unix environments - so, yes, I am sure what ls -l outputs

Stat the file, see if there's anything interesting shown

Honestly, I'd be looking to see if there was some malware on your machine that was trying (badly) to hide itself.  519851 is clearly the wrong number.  Malware kernel modules can make the contents look correct ("cat" returns expected results) while there is still bad stuff in the file.

I would start to get suspicious that you have a rootkit on your systems, which are changing values associated with pkexec in an attempt to hide.

@icarus  hah, snap!

@JaromandaX I have been using Unix systems since 1984.  : )  Which doesn't make me right.  However, I am pretty sure that ls reads the metadata for the file and doesn't count bytes like wc does.  This is why it is reporting the same numbers that melonfsck is getting from python.

@Malcolm - I think that's when I started with some flavour of Unix too!!  ... I guess there are cases where you could be right ... but, for /usr/bin/pkexec this would be concerning to me, considering the nature of pkexec

@JaromandaX, I agree that it is a concern.  There are a lot of reasons why the two numbers aren't the same that are benign (highly fragmented files, sparse files).  However, having the metadata indicate all of this additional allocated space, particularly in a setuid file, looks troubling.

I would definitely remove the setuid bit with chmod 0755 /usr/bin/pkexec until I had worked out what is going on.  This is the work around for some posted pkexec issues, see for example https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000020564.

@Malcolm ; Jaromanda X ; Stephen Harris — thanks for your insights. The system was compromised.

It turned out the system was compromised.
Most likely ld preload was abused to hide malicious actions.
These were boot messages I've seen, looked like all processes ran the same code:
[    9.481844] systemd uses obsolete (PF_INET,SOCK_PACKET)
[   11.791376] udev uses obsolete (PF_INET,SOCK_PACKET)
...
[  101.107952] systemd-logind uses obsolete (PF_INET,SOCK_PACKET)

I took the disk to different machine and saw there is /etc/ld.so.preload file existing. There is no such file in the stock Ubuntu installation.

I choosed to reinstall Ubuntu.
